Why is it that Discover doesn't show some (deb-based) programs?
I think Discover is rather good in Kubuntu 24.04 so that I can routinely use it to install, uninstall and update programs, but sometimes it happens that I install things from the terminal, with a deb installer or even with Apper and such. Thus, I have installed CopyQ (from deb) and Ultracopier (from Apper, with the Ubuntu repos). I don't need them now, and I want to uninstall them. CopyQ is found by Discover, but Ultracopier is not (which Apper or Muon can fiond just fine).


This is a very common occurrence.
What is the difference between the status of such two programs?
I've read (on Reddit etc) as common answer on this that Discover is not "really" a software manager like Synaptic, Muon or even Apper, but more of a "store" etc. But what's the difference between the programs (installed or just available in repos) that it can find and the rest?
That message "not found in the available sources" seems to suggest that Discover doesn't have access to some sources to which apt for example does.
Note that this question refers to classic (deb-based) packages, installable with sudo apt-get install, and has nothing to do with the difference between those and flatpak and snap programs (also accessible in Discover).
